# Template string breaks the iframe

Tags: javascript, typescript, iframe

Objective: I have a very simple Vite + Svelte app that wrap an iframe around a local dev server (localhost on port 5173).

The problem is that it doesn't work when the iframe `src` is dynamic

Here is my Svelte app

###### App.svelte

```html
<script lang="ts">
  const PORT = Number(import.meta.env.VITE_DEV_SERVER_PORT)
  const DEV_SERVER_ENDPOINT = `https://localhost:${PORT}`
</script>

<main>
  <iframe
    title="dev-app"
    src={DEV_SERVER_ENDPOINT}
  />
</main>
```

Once bundled and minified you can see the iframe `src` as a template string

```js
// ...
N(g,"class","svelte-x5ystk"),N(h,"class","svelte-x5ystk")},m(P,j){ee(P,h,j),Z(h,g),f[2](g)},
p:$,i:$,o:$,d(P){P&&z(h),f[2](null)}}}function ge(f,h,g){const P=`https://localhost:${+"5173"}`;
let j=null;async function b(p){const{id:a,type:v,args:l,functionName:i}=p.data;
// ...
```

This `src` breaks the iframe and I can't see my local dev server inside the iframe

```js
P=`https://localhost:${+"5173"}`
```

However, if I write the iframe `src` as plain text, it works as expected

###### App.svelte

```html
<main>
  <iframe
    title="dev-app"
    src={'https://localhost:5173'}
  />
</main>
```

Once bundled and minified with esbuild, I get that

###### bundle.js

```js
// ...
function he(d){let h,g,w;return{c(){h=B("main"),g=B("iframe"),C(g,"title","dev-app"),
X(g.src,w="https://localhost:5173")||C(g,"src",w),C(g,"class","svelte-x5ystk"),C(h,"class",
"svelte-x5ystk")},m(P,S){ee(P,h,S),Z(h,g),d[1](g)},p:$,i:$,o:$,d(P){P&&z(h),d[1](null)}}}
function ge(d,h,g){let w=null;
// ...
```

You can notice that the iframe `src` is a plain text `w="https://localhost:5173"` and the iframe work as expected.

**Is it a known issue regarding iframe?**

NOTE: the minimal Svelte app is uploaded to Google Apps script to be able to develop a Google Apps Script addon from my local computed

##### EDIT

I have found this experiment made by someone else
https://codepen.io/bryanjvolz/pen/NXEEWY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of research, I found the answer. It is explained [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156139610)

```
// I change this
const DEV_SERVER_ENDPOINT = `https://localhost:${PORT}`

// To his
const DEV_SERVER_ENDPOINT = 'https://localhost:' + PORT
```